# Running Eclipse on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-lion

Eclipse runs fine, but I lost the error/warning/todo vertical bar on the right (right next to the new scroll bar).  Does anyone has the same problem?  Thanks!

Comment: If you go to General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, check if the Vertical ruler or Overview ruler checkboxes have been checked.

Comment: Yes, I've checked them, it works on snow leopard... but after I install lion it stop working...

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Was running Helios, upgraded to Indigo to see if that was the issue, problem remains.

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem.
Just 2 cents. I'm running Indigo Build id: 20110615-0604.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Same, ahhhh how do you fix this, SOOO annoying

Figured it out, if you go to system preferences > general > click the "when scrolling" button, to only show the scroll bar when scrolling it fixes it. Mine was previously on "always". I restarted eclipse and it shows the errors/warning message etc now.

Comment: This makes no sense... If you set them to "only when scrolling" (which, in my opinion, sucks), then they always show in Eclipse, along with the error bars.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352990 Bugreport in Eclipse bugtracker.

Comment: Oh, my, god... I owe you the cost of a new laptop, because I was about to throw mine out the window :-).

Answer (score 4):

Now that the Eclipse team fixed the issue, you can also go to "Help" > "Check for updates" and install the platform updates. It fixed the issue without having to change the MacOS Scrollbar settings for me.