# Error indicators in file margin in eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse

I just switched to eclipse indigo and mac osx lion. Everything works fine but errors don't show up in the right file margin like they did in past versions. The code is being built and squiglies are showing up on errors but not in the right file margin. How do I set those errors to show up?

Comment: Here's a work-around: [Running Eclipse on Mac OS X Lion][1]

Will be fixed in 3.7.1


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780269/running-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Preferences, select General/Editors/Text editors/Annotations, and make sure that the errors/warnings are selected to be displayed in the Vertical and Overview rulers.

Comment: Great, I didn't see that before. Unfortunately, the indications are still not showing up. The settings were just like you recommended by default. I opened up my Galileo instance (the settings were the same as you suggested) and the indications were there. In Indigo, I cannot right click that overview ruler, any ideas??

Comment: For me the indications does not show on the right, only the left, but there they are displayed, and that are is clickable as well. I'm also using Lion and Indigo.

Comment: I have the exact same situation. Having those error bars on the right makes it a whole lot easier to navigate my errors!

Comment: I checked now even in Eclipse Helios - it does not work there as well.

Answer (score 2):

From [Running Eclipse on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780269/running-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-lion): 'Figured it out, if you go to system preferences > general > click the "when scrolling" button, to only show the scroll bar when scrolling it fixes it. Mine was previously on "always". I restarted eclipse and it shows the errors/warning message etc now.'