# Eclipse Not Showing Errors on Lefthand Side

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

So I've been using Eclipse on my mac for the past 4 months with no problems but suddenly things are acting up. Before, Eclipse would show me a red dot on the lefthand scroll bar when I was working on a class in a project. Now, for some reason, all it does is grey-out that line number but it does not show me that dot like it used to. I've tried restarting both Eclipse and my computer, I've tried working on different projects and classes, I've made sure a project builder is selected, and I've checked that the "show errors" options are all checked. I do not like having to have another window open to see exactly where all my errors are; I preferred just having the red section on my class screen. Any other suggestions?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try going to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Annotations`, then click on 'Errors', then check "Vertical ruler" under "Show In".

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking here: [Error indicators in file margin in eclipse indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234795/error-indicators-in-file-margin-in-eclipse-indigo)

Open Preferences, select General/Editors/Text editors/Annotations, and make sure that the errors/warnings are selected to be displayed in the Vertical and Overview rulers.

**or**

Figured it out, if you go to system preferences > general > click the "when scrolling" button, to only show the scroll bar when scrolling it fixes it. Mine was previously on "always". I restarted eclipse and it shows the errors/warning message etc now.'