# How can I re-enable variable markers next to the scroll bar?

Tags: eclipse

There used to be line markers on the right-hand side of the window (next to the scroll bar) which marked occurrences of variables or other things (such as TODO's or compiler errors).  They looked liked color-coded dashes.  I could click on a marker and it would jump to that occurrence of the variable in my code.  Or, I could click anywhere in the bar and it would jump to its relative vertical location in the file.

I'm not sure what I did, but the markers disappeared and I can't find a setting to bring them back.  Does anybody know how I can re-enable them?

Also, "Mark Occurrences" is enabled in my editor, and variable occurrences are properly highlighted in my code as normal when I have a variable selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have researched more. I asked a duplicate of this question: [Running Eclipse on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780269/running-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-lion) The solution to the problem can be found there.